# Phonegap 3.0 Build inAppBrowser listeners not working

Tags: ios, cordova

I hope someone can help me figure this out. This is my first Phonegap app, so this could be a fairly elementary mistake on my part. I'm specifically trying to get this to work on iOS. Android will wait until another day.

I'm trying to load a page from an external site (which I do control) using the inAppBrowser. After the user leaves the initial page, it should close and return them to the app. The page opens successfully, but I've tried everything I can think of to get it to close and return to the app, but to no avail.

The function using inAppBrowser looks like this:

```
function open_page() {
     var ref = window.open('http://www.mydomain.com/page1.html', '_blank', 'location=yes,enableViewportScale=no');
     ref.addEventListener('loadstop', function(event) { if(event.url != "http://www.mydomain.com/page1.html") ref.close(); });
     ref.addEventListener('exit', function(event) { alert(event.type); });
}
```

I am using the cloud-based Phonegap Build, and my config.xml file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<widget

...


<access origin="*" />

<preference name="phonegap-version" value="3.0.0" />

<preference name="orientation" value="portrait" />

<preference name="fullscreen" value="true" />

<preference name="stay-in-webview" value="true" />

<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/battery"/>
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/camera"/>
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/contacts"/>
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/file"/>
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/geolocation"/>
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/media"/>
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/network"/>
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/notification"/>

<feature name="InAppBrowser">
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVInAppBrowser" />
</feature>

<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device" /> 
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.camera" /> 
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device-orientation" /> 
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file" /> 
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.globalization" /> 
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.network-information" /> 
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.dialogs" /> 
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.splashscreen" />

<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.core.geolocation" /> 

</widget>
```

Thanks in advance for all help!

Comment: Well, I'm still having this issue. If it helps at all, it looks like the options for inAppBrowser don't work either - i.e. with 'location=yes' there's still no location bar.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your config file-

```
   <access origin="*" browserOnly="true"/>
```

For open link in APP browser use following line, which open link in app browser.
And return back to your application when you closed it.

```
 window.open('http://www.' + email, '_blank', 'location=yes');
```